# using parameter text file in bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, parameters, grep

How can I change 3rd field of records by depending on another file? Is it possible to use awk?

Sorry I am new to this

Example:
Records

```
xxxx xxxx 1234 xxxx
xxxx xxxx 5678 xxxx
```

Parameter (another file)

```
1234,9001
5678,9020
```

My expected output is

```
xxxx xxxx 9001 xxxx
xxxx xxxx 9020 xxxx
```

Glimpse of my code

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh

 SRC=/home

 FILE_LIST=`sqlplus -s idmp_stg/idmp_stg@DTPMPDR07_SUDB << EOF
 set echo off head off feed off pagesize 0 trimspool on linesize 1000 colsep ,
 spool output.csv
 SELECT * from USAGE_TYPE_PARAM;             
 spool off;
 exit;
 EOF`

#Using while loop read values into variables from CSV file and create flat file 
 for    each records
 counter=1
 while IFS=, read V1 V2
 do
 echo "${V1} ${V2}" > param_${counter}.txt
 counter=$(( counter + 1 ))
 done < output.csv


 cd $SRC

 ls D* | while read FILES
 do

  #--this supposed to change the 3rd field of the file but it doesn't show 
  #--an output,       just zero byte file
  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$3=a[$3]}1' FS="," output.csv FS=" " $FILES >  
  final_output.txt

  done`
```

Comment: Yes, already updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$3=a[$3];print}' <(tr , " " <Parameter) Records 
xxxx xxxx 9001 xxxx
xxxx xxxx 9020 xxxx
```

Explanation:

Taking it one piece at a time:

- `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}`

  awk is processing two files, one after the other, one line at a time.  NR is the total number of lines read and FNR is the number of lines read in the current file.  So, when `NR==FNR`, we are in the first file which, in this case, is Parameter.  These commands are therefore executed only while reading Parameter.  `a[$1]=$2` creates a dictionary whose keys are the first field and whose corresponding values are the second field of Parameter.  The `next` command tells awk to ignore the remaining awk commands and skip to the next line.
- `{$3=a[$3];print}`

  Because of the `next` statement above, these commands are only executed when reading the second file.  They change the third field to its new value and print the line.
- `<(tr , " " <Parameter)`

  Unlike Records, the file Parameter is comma-separated.  Here, the translate command, `tr`, is used to convert it from comma-separated to space-separated before `awk` reads it.  The `<(...)` construct is known as process substitution.

#### POSIX or mksh or pdsh

Process substitution is a bash/ksh/zsh extension not supported by all shells.  To run this without process substitution:

```
$ tr , " " <Parameter | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$3=a[$3];print}' - Records 
xxxx xxxx 9001 xxxx
xxxx xxxx 9020 xxxx
```

In this command, the first file argument to `awk` is `-` which means stdin.  The output of `tr` is piped into `awk` to provide this stdin.

This works the same as the previous solution but avoids process substitution.

Comment: It gives me this $ awk `'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$3=a[$3];print}' <(tr , " " <output.csv) /idmp/MJMN/SUN_DR_CALL_TYPE/arc`
**ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected**

Comment: @Vision111 I looked it up and ["AT&T ksh{88,93} (but not pdksh/mksh) support process substitution"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) as well as bash and zsh.  Are you using pdksh or mksh?  Regardless, I added a solution to the answer that avoids process substitution.  Let me know what happens.

Comment: $ **cat sample**
`500000000000925577733300000000000000000000942136326600000GS515050901966485     00*HOME     020140814008504800000000000000      00000
0000020000000000000000000000000000000001   1000 546                   00000000                      NN  N                          N
    5117511307`     RESULT  **$ tr , " " <output.csv | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$3=a[$3];print}' - /idmp/MJMN/SUN_DR_CALL_TYPE/src/sample**
`500000000000925577733300000000000000000000942136326600000GS515050901966485 00*HOME  00000
0000020000000000000000000000000000000001 1000  00000000 NN N N
5117511307 `

Comment: @Vision111 Did `020140814008504800000000000000` appear as a first column in `output.csv`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat Records
xxxx xxxx 1234 xxxx
xxxx xxxx 5678 xxxx

$ cat Parameter
1234,9001
5678,9020

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$3=a[$3]}1' FS="," Parameter FS=" " Records
xxxx xxxx 9001 xxxx
xxxx xxxx 9020 xxxx
```

Set the Field Separator variable at the end before the file name to set it for that particular file.